# Adding list in formatted way?

Tags: java, python, list, arraylist, jython

I'm bukkit python/jython coder, but I'm struggling adding my list to config. Since I can't get it to work with Bukkit API, I got idea to do it on more Pythonic way. I know how to write files using this format (for example):

```
fo = open("%s/TwistedJobs/config.yml"%pluginlocation2, "wb")
fo.write("Farmers:")
fo.close
```

I have config YAML file, in which I want to store player names with their job, here's example:

```
Farmers:
- Player
- Player1
Miners:
- Player2
- Player3
Traders:
- Player4
- Player5
```

Now I want to add players upon an event to list. For example, Farmers list. There is no problem with fetching player names and triggering event, that is not problem. Plan is to get that arraylist and add another player name there (I've done that already). Now I want to add that new arraylist in config, but how? They must be in format given above (config example)...

This is how I fetch arraylist and add new players to same list (it's working perfectly, but I don't know how to put that new list into config, since I can't get BukkitAPI way to work):

```
list = pyplugin.getCfg().getStringList("Farmers")
list1 = list.add(event.getPlayer().getName())
```

Thanks in advance, Amar!

Answer (score 0):

No idea about the Bukkit API, but a `list` in python usually must me appended:

```
list.append(event.getPlayer().getName())
```

Also putting some traceback or errors might help anybody trying to answer your questions.

Comment: I don't have any errors since I don't know how to do it lol. Also, this is arraylist and I have to "add" things inside it, it's similiar to pythons list. I can edit java arraylists because of jython... And that part works, I just don't know how to add new list to a config file :S